# A simple evaluation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the equation $X^2+4Y^2+9Z^2=14X+28Y+42Z+147$ where $X,Y,Z$ are real numbers. Then what is the value of $X+2Y+3Z$? I tried with $X+2Y+3Z=A$ and obtained $A^2-14A-147=2(2XY+6YZ+3ZX)$. I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: You sure that you didn’t miscopy +147, perhaps it should say -147, as in $X^2+4Y^2+9Y^2=14X+28Y+42Z-147$.

Answer (score 1):

By completing the squares you rewrite the equation as

$$(X-7)^2+(2Y-7)^2+(3Z-7)^2-3\cdot49=147.$$

As such, this is the equation of an ellipsoid, and it cannot match that of a plane so that $X+2Y+3Z$ is not a constant and the solution is not unique.

But if we assume a mistake in the problem statement ($-147$ instead of $147$), the ellipsoid degenerates to a single point and

$$X+2Y+3Z=21.$$